# What endpoint is best for a 3PL to use to push additional order info to Skubana? (i.e. Lot Code)

Tags: api

The customer's 3PL tracks lot codes and the customer wants to be able to see that information in Skubana.

Answer (score 0):

they can create a custom field called lot code using https://documentation.skubana.com/spec/#operation/putCustomFieldDefinitionsUsingPUT and then add values for this field using https://documentation.skubana.com/spec/#operation/putCustomFieldValuesUsingPUT. If they want just one step they can use the update orders endpoint https://documentation.skubana.com/spec/#operation/postOrderUsingPOST_1 and can use one of the custom fields if they’re not used  but it won’t be labeled lot code.

This information will not currently push to native sales channels, but it can be stored in Skubana.